# Resize Image with text in tableview cell UI chat swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, chat

I'm trying to set up a chat app, but currently, I'm stuck on a UI point that the UI part does not handle properly. Now, I'm trying to show an image with a text message, but my UI part is not working properly. Please check the attached screenshots.

**The screenshot is taken from an iPhone.**

[image]

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

[image]

**Code:-**

I posted only for the sender section as the same code was used for the left side (receiver side).

```
import UIKit

class SenderTVC: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var senderImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSenderMsg: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSenderTime: UILabel!
}
```

**Xib**

[image]

Question: How to show an image with text as shown in the original image(second screenshot)?

Can someone please explain to me how to show the same cell with a big-size image with text in the `table view` cell, I've tried but have no results yet.

Comment: You are already showing both an image and text in a cell as shown in your first screenshot. Shouldn't your question be more about how to make the image bigger? You provide no details about how your cell is setup. Most likely you just need better constraints.

Comment: @HangarRash, you are right, Could you please help me? How to show a bigger image with multi-line text?

Comment: Have you tried MessageKit?, why reinvent the wheel ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

set constraint to ImageView -> width and height for example 150x150

and set ImageView "**Content Mode**" property to "**Aspect Fill**"

after that set a constraint to Text or label and height >= 10
and Line = 0
and set the constraint to time label

all your image and label must have top and bottom constraint to do grow the tableviewcell height automatically

you can check this link may be helpful:
https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing this. I will check and update you.

Comment: @ShamDhiman did your issue solve?

Comment: No, I'm working on it.

Comment: Did you implement my solution? @ShamDhiman

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: No, now I'm implementing your solution. I will update you give me some time, please.